# Jersey SSE Eventoutput writes are not going to client unless closed

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jersey-2.0

I have jquery client expecting  Jersey SSE events from java servlet/ JAX-RS server.

I have this client code initiating request to server

```
var source = new EventSource("api/chat");
$(source).on("message", function (evt) {
    var chatMsg = JSON.parse(evt.originalEvent.data);    
    $("#chat").val(chatMsg.userid + ": " + chatMsg.msg + "\n" + $("#chat").val());
});
```

This is the server code to push messages using eventoutput

```
JsonObject obj = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("userid", userid)
                .add("msg", msg)
                .build();
OutboundEvent evt = new OutboundEvent.Builder()
                .mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .data(JsonObject.class, obj)
                .build();   

eventOutput.write(evt);
eventOutput.close();
```

What is happening here is client is not getting any response what so ever if didnt use `eventoutput.close()`.

As per documentation this close is not required or at least not mentioned anywhere. But without that messages are queued and they will be delivered only when I try to close the server. Thats strange.
  I found a workaround with `close()` which helps to flush messages but of course with side effect of closing the connection. Though Connection gets recreated automatically from client side, I am just trying to understand why close is required in my case ?
  Has anyone faced similar issue ?

Is it something to do with some standard response stream buffer size? My message is chat string typed by user which can be even 1 character in length.

I am using GlassFish server 4 and jersey 2.9.1 version jars. Browser is chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as you and finally figured it out after opening wireshark.  Namely, the data was being sent only on the HTTP response body and not streamed/chunked in.  In other words, if the `eventOutput.close` was not explictly called, it wouldn't be sent.

First, check your proxy (if you're using one) to make sure there's no buffering on that side.

Finally, check if there's any filters on your java webapp that may be collecting the responses.  In my case, it was the gzip filter in Dropwizard that was holding the TCP packets from being sent.

I wrote in a bit more detail at [JERSEY-jira](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3000)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem,
I resolved **REMOVING** in my ResourceConfig.java, if you had:

```
EncodingFilter.enableFor(this, GZipEncoder.class);
```

Answer (score -2):

`EventSource` is not a jQuery object (unless you're loading some sort of plug-in).

```
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
}, false);

source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    // Connection was opened.
}, false);

source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
        // Connection was closed.
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: This answer is not at all related to my question. As I mentioned earlier I am getting message delivered at client with explicit call to close on server or if i try to close the server. And BTW even though eventsource is not jquery object I am wrapping it like $(source) before calling on method on it. Jquery code given in original question is perfectly fine. Just that server is not able to push without close call.

Comment: Understood. I tried to use the jQuery wrapper as you've shown and couldn't get it work work properly. I had to use the native `onMessage` handler. Also, I'm running on Glassfish promoted build b08 which includes Jersey 2.10.1.